# Problem with Post action on Strapi via Python

Tags: python, post, strapi

I'm trying to send a POST and I get this error:

{"data":null,"error":{"status":400,"name":"ValidationError","message":"Missing "data" payload in the request body","details":{}}}
In [ ]:

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
myToken = '256e8f598edc0990b39dbfe8c4acf39ec83ee3a1a8f212a7656b3892585755c52857503a356ed003fa6b1f5f4b89fc34b0aa64000bb1bf5bba75257a0128365c75aa96a8cb4ed7a32e7fc7b5ec899ae6d2633a7004ef7f991b8ca6e6bdac4a3a75954425f95cc1a209e09272b5582f58690759f81aecb506070c3c19b3cdac2f'
myUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/api/countries'
head = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(myToken), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(head)
```

Get request & response (working well):

```
response = session.get(myUrl)
print (response.text)

{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "attributes":{
            "name":"United States",
            "createdAt":"2022-04-09T04:15:13.925Z",
            "updatedAt":"2022-04-09T04:15:15.226Z",
            "publishedAt":"2022-04-09T04:15:15.220Z"
         }
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "page":1,
         "pageSize":25,
         "pageCount":1,
         "total":1
      }
   }
}
```

Post request & response:

```
data = json.dumps(['data', {'name': 'United States'}])

response = session.post(myUrl, data = data)

print (response.text)


{
   "data":null,
   "error":{
      "status":400,
      "name":"ValidationError",
      "message":"Missing \"data\" payload in the request body",
      "details":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did the solution for that,

First of all: I changed the "data" to "json"

```
data = {'data': {'name': 'United states'}}


request = session.post(myUrl, json = data)

print (request.text)
```

Comment: +1 Worked for me the same way when Postman produced the same error after trying to send an update to a collection with a request body JSON made up of collection object key-value pairs. It seems that Strapi v4 wants the data to be input as a JSON object with key, "data" . . . So be it.